# Load/import CSV file in to mongodb using PYSPARK

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to know how to load/import a CSV file in to mongodb using pyspark. I have a csv file named cal.csv placed in the desktop. Can somebody share the code snippet.

Comment: you want to read the csv from desktop using pyspark and then save it in mongodb, right?

Comment: yes! absolutely correct. I want to import the CSV file and store it in mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read the `csv` as pyspark dataframe.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
sql = SQLContext(sc)

df = sql.read.csv("cal.csv", header=True, mode="DROPMALFORMED")
```

Then write it to `mongodb`,

```
df.write.format('com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource').mode('append')\
        .option('database',NAME).option('collection',COLLECTION_MONGODB).save()
```

Specify the `NAME` and `COLLECTION_MONGODB` as created by you.

Also, you need to give conf and packages alongwith spark-submit according to your version,

```
/bin/spark-submit --conf "spark.mongodb.inuri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/DATABASE.COLLECTION_NAME?readPreference=primaryPreferred"
                  --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/DATABASE.COLLECTION_NAME" 
                  --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.2.0
                  tester.py
```

Specify `COLLECTION_NAME` and `DATABASE` above. `tester.py` assuming name of the code file. For more information, refer [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/python-api/).

Comment: Did you find the answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. database:people   Collection:con

```
pyspark --conf "spark.mongodb.input.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.con?readPreference=primaryPreferred" \
    --conf "spark.mongodb.output.uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.con" \
    --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector_2.11:2.3.0


from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

my_spark = SparkSession \
         .builder \
         .appName("myApp") \
         .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.con") \
         .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/people.con") \
         .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read.csv(path = "file:///home/user/Desktop/people.csv", header=True, inferSchema=True)

df.printSchema()

df.write.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").mode("append").option("database","people").option("collection", "con").save()
```

Next go to mongo and check if collection is wrtten by following below steps

```
mongo
show dbs
use people
show collections
db.con.find().pretty()
```